# Card.io Android SDK how to change title text and color on manual entry screen

Tags: android, card.io

I'm using Card.IO SDK for Android. On the screen that shows the scanned card image and manual entry texts, I need to change the action bar title color and text. Right now, it's blue and showing 'Card details'(on newer devices) and 'card.io - card details'(on gingerbread devices). Is there a way to achieve that ? Is it also possible to change the color of the buttons (cancel and submit) on that screen?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way for you to control those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it's possible but you only have few customisation's options on the Card.IO Android SDK.

You will find the available parameters on the JavaDoc : http://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardIOActivity.html

You should follow the Card.IO repository, it's regularly updated and - maybe this feature will be released.